# Android 4.1 layer-list not loading background image

Tags: android

I've the following XML that works perfectly on 4.2 device but fails to load the image on 4.1 devices (the vertical_back that is specified in the bitmap tag):

```
    </shape>
</item>
<item>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
        <stroke android:width="4dp" android:color="@android:color/black" />

    </shape>
</item>
```

Any ideas?

Thanks